# Object Polymorphism

Tags: java

I have a project for school that has a logIn and shows a table using a method that is corresponding with the account but when I log in with the other accounts it also calls the main class' table please help me, Im a first year IT student and this is my first project any help will be much appreciated.

Here's the source code:
**The LogIn:**

```
public class LogIn implements ActionListener{
//GUI
 static JLabel userLabel;
 static JTextField userText;
 static JLabel passwordLabel;
 static JPasswordField passwordText;
 static JButton loginButton ;
 static JLabel success;

public static void main(String[]args) {    
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Activities/Task Manager Log in");
    frame.setSize(350, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();    
    frame.add(panel);
 
    placeComponents(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {

    panel.setLayout(null);

    userLabel = new JLabel("User");
    userLabel.setBounds(10,30,80,25);
    panel.add(userLabel);

    userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100,30,165,25);
    panel.add(userText);

    passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    passwordLabel.setBounds(10,70,80,25);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);

    passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
    passwordText.setBounds(100,70,165,25);
    panel.add(passwordText);

    loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    loginButton.setBounds(10, 110, 80, 25);
    loginButton.addActionListener(new LogIn());
    panel.add(loginButton);
   
    success = new JLabel("");
    success.setBounds(10, 140, 300, 25);
    panel.add(success);
    
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    String user = userText.getText();
    String password = passwordText.getText();

    if (user.equals("Rod Vince Tolosa")&& password.equals("123456") ) {
        success.setText("Login Successful!");
        Tolosa.showtable();
    }
    else if (user.equals("Paul Naethan Bustillo")&& password.equals("654321") ) {
        success.setText("Login Successful!");
        Bustillo.showtable();
    }
    else if (user.equals("Christia Anna Sarguet")&& password.equals("123123") ) {
        success.setText("Login Successful!");
        Sarguet.showtable();
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Login Details");
        userText.setText(null);
        passwordText.setText(null);
    }
}
```

}

**The tables class:**

```
public class Tolosa {    
    
   public JFrame Tasks;    
    Tolosa(){    
    Tasks=new JFrame("Rod Vince Tolosa Tasks/Activities");    
        String column[]={"SUBJECT","ACTIVITY","DATE","TIME"};
        String data[][]={{"STS","Film Review","05/21/21","12:00 AM"},
                          {"Entrepreneurial Mind","Final Paper","05/15/21","4:30 PM"},    
                          {"Purposive Communication","Task 8","05/27/21","11:59 PM"}, 
                          {"GEPC","Poster Project","06/03/21","12:00 AM"},
                          {"InfoMan","Project Database","06/08/21","1:30 PM"},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""},
                          {"","","",""}};         
    JTable jt=new JTable(data,column);    
    jt.setBounds(30,40,200,300);          
    JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(jt);    
    Tasks.add(sp);          
    Tasks.setSize(650,400);    
    Tasks.setVisible(true);    
    Tasks.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}    
    public static void showtable() {    
        new Tolosa();    
    }     
}
//Inheritance
class Bustillo extends Tolosa{

    public JFrame Tasks;    
    Bustillo(){    
    Tasks=new JFrame("Paul Naethan Bustillo Tasks/Activities");    
    String column[]={"COURSE SUBJECT","ACTIVITY","DEADLINE","TIME"};
    String data[][]={ {"Probability and Statistics","Final Quiz","06/3/21","4:30 PM"},    
            {"Entrepreneurial Mind","Final Paper","05/15/21","4:30 PM"},    
            {"Purposive Communication","Task 7","05/19/21","11:59 PM"}, 
            {"GEPC","Poster Project","06/03/21","12:00 AM"},
            {"Information Management","Final Project Presentation","06/08/21","1:30 PM"},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""},
            {"","","",""}};
JTable jt=new JTable(data,column);    
jt.setBounds(30,40,200,300);          
JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(jt);    
Tasks.add(sp);          
Tasks.setSize(650,400);    
Tasks.setVisible(true);    
Tasks.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
} 
//Polymorphism
public static void showtable() {    
        new Bustillo();    
    }     
}
```

Comment: Please make this into a [mcve] - it will be easier for somebody to help you if the code in your question is reduced to just the amount of code necessary to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: O please, use interpunction! Your current post is hard to read.

Comment: My bad this is my first post.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the method you're calling is `static` which doesn't work well with polymorphism. There's plenty of articles online and answers here on stackoverflow that discuss it (Few examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28123043/2464528), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52250764/2464528), & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13696021/2464528)).

For a very simple example, try running this code and see what happens:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new B();
    }
}

class A {
    public A() {
        hi();
    }
    public static void hi() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
        hi();
    }
    public static void hi() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, bro I fixed it by changing the constructor to a method and calling it using an instance of the class.

Comment: @RodVinceTolosa that behavior isn’t guaranteed if you’re still using static. Take a look at the 3rd link in my answer.